# GAS - Google Docs API - getActiveDocument().getCursor().getOffset() returns unexpected '1' for cursor at end of line

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api, clasp

I use CLASP therefore my dummy code is displayed as TypeScript.

If I write *"test"* into my google document and let the cursor be at what I would expect index **4** of the string, the Apps Script API returns **1** when calling:

```
const activeDocument = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
const cursor = activeDocument.getCursor();
const cursorOffset = cursor.getOffset();
```

This is a true headage for me because when I rest the cursor at index **1** for the string *"test"*, then the same code returns the expected index **1**.

How should anyone know that the cursor is at **end of line** or at **the actual index 1** of the `SurroundingText` for the cursor `Position` when the offset is the same?

Comment: Thanks for discovering a typo. Though still the same problem.

Comment: Seems that I've solved this by using the getSurroundingTextOffset() with the cursor position.
See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/position#getSurroundingTextOffset() for more details.

Comment: It makes sense to you to post the solution as an answer. It would be good for future readers.

Comment: Solution posted.

Comment: You posted the solution as part of the question. You should post it as an answer, not part of the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Solution posted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using the `getSurroundingTextOffset()` instead of `getOffset()`.

```
const activeDocument = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
const cursor = activeDocument.getCursor();
const cursorOffset = cursor.getSurroundingTextOffset();
```

NOTE: This makes sense in case of using the `getSurroundingText()`.

read more at the docs: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/position#getSurroundingTextOffset()